# How to use PDO prepared statement if php condition is met

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to execute an sql statement if a condition is met based on POST data.
Attached are links to screenshots of the printed array, and the table it should be querying. I do not get an error, but nothing happens in the database if data does = 1, which should run the stmt and drop/add as needed, the else statment instead is triggered every time. I am also just getting a blank html page now, the print_r and echos are not running. still no error....
Code below, thanks. (connection info hidden for obvious reasons)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDsI.jpg

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Addition Logic</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $db_host = "host";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_pass = "pass";
    $db_name = "name";
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product
        SELECT new_prod_id, name, company, image FROM add_new_product WHERE new_prod_ID = '".$key."'
        DELETE FROM add_new_product WHERE id = '".$key."';";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    print_r($_POST);
        foreach($_POST as $data)
        $key = key($data);
        echo $key;
        $user_ID = "select user_ID from add_new_product where new_prod_ID ='".$key."' ";
        echo $user_ID;
        $username = "select username from users where usersID ='".$user_ID."' ";
        echo $username;
        $user_email = "select email from users where usersID = '".$user_ID."' ";
        echo $user_email;

        if ($data == "1"){
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Data was 1";
        }
        else{
            $msg = "Hello '".$username."', you recently submitted a product to 4UM. We regret to inform you that your product was not approved, likely because of insufficent proof uploaded \nIf this was not accurate,
            please resubmit your product with improved proof so we may approve it. \nThank you for using 4UM!";
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
            mail($user_email, "4UM New Product Rejection",$msg);
        }


    ?>
     
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the `var_export` of your `$_POST`?

Comment: var_export seems to return NULL

Comment: Hi, I think you may have forgotten to make your method type on html form to post. `<form method='post'>`, kindly confirm, if that is the case.

Comment: and if you're using xhr, fetch or similar confirm you're setting your methods/headers and body/forndata properly.

Comment: Hi Ezekiel, yes the form method is post, it is ```<form action="/~yalevy/addition.php" method="POST" name="approval">``` I do not believe I am suing xhr or fetch.

Comment: I would not be getting the array to print in the screenshot if it was not posting the data, correct?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Why do you claim to use prepared statements, but build your SQL queries by hand? This is dangerous, as it opens your application for SQL injections

Comment: The page gets a 500 error in the console, but not on page load. I am not sure about building the query by hand, I am not asking for any input from the user besides clicking checkboxes for the post data, so I don't know where they could inject anything? I am very new to working with PDO though so maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: My print_r and echo statements aren't running so i think something is failing earlier on...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue as to why you're always seeing your else statement execute is because you have omitted braces on your `foreach`. While this is valid code, it will only execute the next statement as part of the loop and none others below it. This means that your code is actually doing:

```php
foreach($_POST as $data) {
    $key = key($data);
}
echo $key;
$user_ID = "select user_ID from add_new_product where new_prod_ID ='".$key."' ";
echo $user_ID;
...
```

This means that by the time your `if` condition is evaluated, `$data` will be set to the last value in your iteration, which in this case will be index 26 with a value of 0.

Even if you did add the braces, I'm not sure exactly how you have intended your code to work as [`key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) only works on arrays and "returns the index element of the current array position", however, you are iterating over your `$_POST` array which according to your screenshot contains only `int` as values. Meaning that your loop will be attempting `key(1)`, `key(1)` and `key(0)`.

If you were looking to get the index of the value, you can use the following where `$index` will be the index:

```php
foreach($_POST as $index => $data) {
    ...
```

Assuming that you fix the above, your code should look something like:

```php
print_r($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $index => $data) {
    ...

    if ($data == 1) {
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Data was 1";
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you're using prepared statements but inserting the value of `$key` using string concatenation which can open you up to [SQLi attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection), you should instead use [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). If `$key` is intended to be the value set inside of your `foreach`, you can use `bindParam` before your `execute` within the loop.

Comment: I'll look into the sqli injection issues once I can get it to run at all haha. Right now i am getting a 500 error in the console on loading the page with your edits, and without them.

Comment: I hope that helped anyway.